# Como restar 2 columnas derivadas de una funcion en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 columnas ambas generadas por medio de 2 funciones diferentes, como son muchos datos la consulta demora 190 segundos.

Ejemplo de lo que no quiero hacer:

- Quiero restar el resultado de ambas columnas pero no quiero que demore otros 190 segundos ya que debo ocupar nuevamente las funciones.

Es posible hacer la resta de forma mas rápida?

Ejemplo de lo que quiero evitar:

```
Select
 Funcion1(parametros) Columna1,
 Funcion2(parametros) Columna2,
 Funcion1(parametros)-Funcion2(parametros) Columna3
From
 Tabla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar el resultado de lo que te devuelve cada función a una variable y realizar un select de esas variables:

```
declare @primerResultado as decimal
declare @segundoResultado as decimal

set @primerResultado = Funcion1(parametros)
set @segundoResultado = Funcion2(parametros)

Select @primerResultado - @segundoResultado as ResultadoFinal
```

También podrías agregar el código de las funciones para ver si hay algo que se pueda mejorar en las funciones para que no demoren tanto.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero que la resta no la realices en la BD; es decir que la realices en el código de la aplicación.

Revisa lo que se hace en las funciones; a estas agregale sean [DETERMINISTIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html); otras cosas a considerar es si en las funciones haces uso por ejemplo de Query para retornar un valor agregues indices de cada campo en el WHERE, JOIN... que se usa a fin d agilazar la comparación.